# C# mongodb Program use Model base map and return base object Collection

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql

the class MainDataBase:

```
internal abstract class MainDataBase {}
```

and other 2 class:

```
internal class MainEduData : MainDataBase {}
internal class MainWorkData : MainDataBase {}
```

How can I get a collection contains all maindata like this?

```
var datas = rc.GetCollection<MainDataBase>("MainData");
var allDatas = await datas.Find("{}").ToListAsync();
```

this code will throw, because the abstract class `MainDataBase` can't use `ctor`, and may be can't `DeserializeObject` to right object.

Comment: You seem to be talking about discriminators and Polymorphism. Where have you defined the collection to use? Also take a look at [this link](http://pastebin.com/9UweEKBe) which bases of an older version of the driver but might still give some pointers.

Comment: @Felipe Oriani
Thank you for your reply. But I can't open the link. And what do you mean 'defined the collection to use'?

Comment: the collection `MainData` exists?